# Accessing component embedded in template Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an `ng-template` which I use to create a model with a form on it on top of one of my other components as follows:

```
<div>
    <h1>Main component content...</h1>
    <button (click)="modals.show(newthingmodal)">Create New Thing</button>
</div>
<ng-template #newthingmodal>
    <input id="example"/>
    <app-component #subcomponent></app-component> <--- I want a reference to this component
    <button (click)="saveAndClose()">Save</button>
</ng-template>
```

In my main component's code, I can get the `TemplateRef` for the modal as follows:

```
@ViewChild("newthingmodal") modalTpl!: TemplateRef;
```

However, I need access to the the component embedded within the template (#subcomponent). Is there any way to access this from the main component (i.e. where `modalTpl` would be defined)?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can add this to your component:

```
@ViewChild('subcomponent') subComponent: AppComponent; // Or whatever class that component is
```

Then in your enclosing component use it like `this.subComponent.DoStuff();`.